# What is the exact meaning of "vice versa" here?

Tags: word-usage

Here is a sentence:

*We have shown that the increase in A decreased B, and vice versa.*

Here, I want to know which the exact meaning of this sentence is between these:

1. The increase in A decreased B, and the decrease B increased A.
2. The increase in A decreased B, and the decrease A increased B.

If the first is correct, how can I make the sentence in the second meaning using "vice versa"?

Comment: The meaning of the sentence is "the increase in A decreased B, and **an increase in B decreased A**".  [That's what *vice versa* means: in reverse order from the way something has been stated.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vice-versa)

Comment: Not necessarily. If it were a scientific paper I would want it spelled out exactly, not rely on guesswork as to the intent.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, it is a scientific paper, and I think you are right. I will correct the sentence without the expression. Thank you!

Comment: @Tetsujin - True, in a scientific paper, I wouldn't expect to see something like "vice versa", but informally, I can't imagine interpreting it any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using *vice versa* there, possibly at the cost of clarity:

> An increase in A caused B to decrease, and vice versa.

You wouldn't use the definite article, **the**.

Does a decrease in A cause B to increase?

Comment: Thank you! But, can you explain the reason the sentence we gave sacrificed the clarity?

Comment: @Sungil: I explained with my question, the final sentence.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I am really not good at English, so I am not possible to understand what you meant.. Please explain me in more detail.

Comment: There is some opportunity for reader confusion. **Vice versa** means "the same statement but with the order of the constituents reversed", however sometimes it will be defined as "the opposite" or "the inverse", and misunderstanding of the phrase could lead to confusion about whether a decrease also has some effect, even though the statement speaks only of increase as a factor.

Comment: I fully understand your explanation. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

We may never know, without the full context; because vice versa simply means "the other way round".

In this case it could just as easily mean

> The increase in B decreased A

"We have showed" tells me it's either not by a professional writer, or the writer is non-native English.
It should be "We have shown".

That makes me think the rest is unreliable too.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. :) Thank you for your comment.